# How to parse JSON file in flutter

Tags: json, flutter, parsing, dart

I'm getting an error when Calling API, I'm unable to parse data in the bean class.

My API Service code is :

```
  // Get all Hotels list from the API url
  Future<List<Hotel>> getHotels() async {
    final response = await http.get(Uri.parse(apiUrl));

    ///// checking the status code is successful
    if (response.statusCode == 200) {
      // print(response.body);
      return getHotelList(response.body);
    } else {
      throw Exception('Unable to fetch data from API');
    }
  }


  ////// Convert response to Hotel object List
  List<Hotel> getHotelList(String responseBody) {
 //  final parsed = json.decode(responseBody).cast<Map<String, dynamic>>();
    final parsed = json.decode(responseBody).cast<String,dynamic>();
    return parsed.map<Hotel>((json) => Hotel.fromJson(json)).toList();
  }
```

My Beans Class is

```
class Hotel {
  int status;
  List<Data> data;

  Hotel({this.status, this.data});

  Hotel.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    status = json['status'];
    if (json['data'] != null) {
      data = new List<Data>();
      json['data'].forEach((v) {
        data.add(new Data.fromJson(v));
      });
    }
  }

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() {
    final Map<String, dynamic> data = new Map<String, dynamic>();
    data['status'] = this.status;
    if (this.data != null) {
      data['data'] = this.data.map((v) => v.toJson()).toList();
    }
    return data;
  }
}

class Data {
  int id;
  String title;
  String description;
  String address;
  String postcode;
  String phoneNumber;
  String latitude;
  String longitude;
  Image image;

  Data(
      {this.id,
        this.title,
        this.description,
        this.address,
        this.postcode,
        this.phoneNumber,
        this.latitude,
        this.longitude,
        this.image});

  Data.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    id = json['id'];
    title = json['title'];
    description = json['description'];
    address = json['address'];
    postcode = json['postcode'];
    phoneNumber = json['phoneNumber'];
    latitude = json['latitude'];
    longitude = json['longitude'];
    image = json['image'] != null ? new Image.fromJson(json['image']) : null;
  }

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() {
    final Map<String, dynamic> data = new Map<String, dynamic>();
    data['id'] = this.id;
    data['title'] = this.title;
    data['description'] = this.description;
    data['address'] = this.address;
    data['postcode'] = this.postcode;
    data['phoneNumber'] = this.phoneNumber;
    data['latitude'] = this.latitude;
    data['longitude'] = this.longitude;
    if (this.image != null) {
      data['image'] = this.image.toJson();
    }
    return data;
  }
}

class Image {
  String small;
  String medium;
  String large;

  Image({this.small, this.medium, this.large});

  Image.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    small = json['small'];
    medium = json['medium'];
    large = json['large'];
  }

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() {
    final Map<String, dynamic> data = new Map<String, dynamic>();
    data['small'] = this.small;
    data['medium'] = this.medium;
    data['large'] = this.large;
    return data;
  }
}
```

Error Im getting is

```
E/flutter (30141): [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(199)] Unhandled Exception: NoSuchMethodError: Class 'CastMap<String, dynamic, String, dynamic>' has no instance method 'map' with matching arguments.
E/flutter (30141): Receiver: Instance of 'CastMap<String, dynamic, String, dynamic>'
E/flutter (30141): Tried calling: map<Hotel>(Closure: (dynamic) => Hotel)
E/flutter (30141): Found: map<K2, V2>((K, V) => MapEntry<K2, V2>) => Map<K2, V2>
E/flutter (30141): #0      Object.noSuchMethod (dart:core-patch/object_patch.dart:54:5)
```

It looks like errors are generated with the parsing data to a list that has done through the following code in the API services file.

```
  List<Hotel> getHotelList(String responseBody) {
 //  final parsed = json.decode(responseBody).cast<Map<String, dynamic>>();
    final parsed = json.decode(responseBody).cast<String,dynamic>();
    return parsed.map<Hotel>((json) => Hotel.fromJson(json)).toList();
  }
```

Can you please check and guide me on how to resolve this? Any help on this would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
List<Hotel> getHotelList(String responseBody) {
    final parsed = json.decode(responseBody);
    final List<dynamic> hotels = parsed["data"];
    return hotels.map((json) => Hotel.fromJson(json)).toList();
  }
```

Comment: I have tried this but still getting an null error as follows.                                          
   Unhandled Exception: NoSuchMethodError: The method 'map' was called on null.
E/flutter (30766): Receiver: null
E/flutter (30766): Tried calling: map<Hotel>(Closure: (dynamic) => Hotel)
E/flutter (30766): #0      Object.noSuchMethod (dart:core-patch/object_patch.dart:54:5)

Comment: could you provide your response ? Print the response body before decoding

Comment: Sure, data is receiving in the following format before the decoding. {
  "status": 200,
   "data": [
    {
      "id": 1,
     "title": "Down-sized 4thgeneration leverage",
      "description": "Distincti",
      "address": "testing",
      "postcode": "42503-7193",
     "phoneNumber": "387-842-0455x71431",
    "latitude": "-60.964344",
  "longitude": "-12.024244",
     "image": {
        "small": "http://lorempixel.com/200/200/cats/1/",
        "medium": "http://lorempixel.com/400/400/cats/1/",
         "large": "http://lorempixel.com/800/800/cats/1/"
      }
    },

Comment: Now it works. Thank you very much for the help. really appreciate that.